# Calculate intermediate summary in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to calculate the intermediate result in jasper(using iReport designer),intermediate result is shown in bold below, 

**Unit-ID  Currency  Amount**
A01       USD           150
A01       USD           300
A01       CAD           200
A01       CAD           200
--------------------------------
**A01       USD           450**
**A01       CAD           400**
--------------------------------
A02       Rs              150
A02       Rs              300
A02       CAD           200
A02       CAD           150
--------------------------------
**A02       Rs              450**
**A02       CAD           350**
-------------------------------

Is there any way to do this using same records (without hitting the DB again to calculate the summary) ? Something like, I will calculate intermediate sum currency-wise and display the summary when unit changes(A01 to A02).? If I group by Unit-Id and currency I will be able to display the result when currency changes, but I want to display it(all together) when unit-id changes,

I am using Stored procedure to get the result in jasper.

Comment: In jasper create a group on unit-id  and on currency put then drag your amount into the footer.

Comment: If i do that it will display the summary whenever there is a change in  currency right? I wanted to display the summary when group changes, If i put it in unit-id group footer It will show only last row of summary not all..

Comment: it is all in the Evaluation time all tho both are in the Unit ID group you want the currency to evaluate time to be currency. you also want the variables to reset on unit ID